# Angular 4 app dont working under IE 9 and 10

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

Developing the application on Angular 4. Dont working under IE 9,10, under IE working. The error in debugger is Object.isFrozen: the argument is not an object. The my project.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.4.0",
"@angular/common": "^4.4.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.4.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.4.0",
"@angular/forms": "^4.4.0",
"@angular/http": "^4.4.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.0",
"@angular/router": "^4.4.0",
"blob-polyfill": "^1.0.20150320",
"classlist-polyfill": "^1.2.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
"formdata-polyfill": "^2.0.4",
"intl": "^1.2.5",
"moment": "^2.19.1",
"primeng": "^4.2.2",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "^5.0.1",
"tedious": "^2.0.0",
"tslib": "^1.7.1",
"typedarray": "0.0.6",
"web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
"zone.js": "^0.8.10"
 },
```

The my polyfill.ts

```
 import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es7/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';
 import 'core-js/es7/array';
 import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
 import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
 import 'core-js/es6/promise';
 import 'classlist-polyfill';
 import 'web-animations-js';
 import 'intl';
 import 'typedarray';
 import 'formdata-polyfill';
 import 'blob-polyfill';
 import 'core-js/client/shim';
 import 'reflect-metadata';
 require('zone.js/dist/zone');
 import 'ts-helpers';
 if (process.env.ENV === 'build') {
   } else {
  Error['stackTraceLimit'] = Infinity;
  require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
 }
```

What I'm doing is wrong or what's missing in polyfills.ts?

Comment: can you show us the code using .isFrozen method?

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't work"... Error messages?

Comment: Are you using angular-cli?

Comment: @user2010955 I dont using method isFrozen in the application.

Comment: @msanford: Yes, under the expression "does not work" I understand error messages

Comment: @wdanda: I dont using angular-cli.

Comment: @Andrew I mean "please explain _specifically how_ it does not work; do you have error messages? If so, please post them."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you start a brand new project with angular cli (i.e. "ng new appname") and tweak the polyfills.ts file. You'll need to uncomment the lines with 
'...core/es6/...' and classlist.js by running 'npm install --save classlist.js'.

Then try a simple hello world and take see if it works.

More info about Angular browser requirements here: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#mandatory-polyfills